# I want to run jquery code after the angular js completed all its rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to hide and show my div chart. it should work with pages (Add, edit , saveas).
the toggling of div is done through checkbox when i checked on checkbox div show and when its unchecked div is hided. In addnew page i stored the value of checkbox i.e(true/false). when user go to edit page if checkbox value is true it should show divchart and vice and versa for false value.

Comment: Which routing mechanism are you using  `ui-router` or `ng-route` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ngShow?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

I think it's better to avoid mixing jquery into AngularJS code if possible.

For the future, you should format the code to make it more readable.